# Equivalent of numpy.nan_to_num in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, numerical

How can I achieve behavior equivalent to numpy's `numpy.nan_to_num` function in C/C++?

Specificiation for non-python programmers:

> Replace nan with zero and inf with finite numbers.
>
> Returns an array or scalar replacing Not a Number (NaN) with zero,
>   (positive) infinity with a very large number and negative infinity
>   with a very small (or negative) number. ... NaN is replaced by
>   zero, and infinity (-infinity) is replaced by the largest (smallest or
>   most negative) floating point value that fits in the output dtype.

Comment: C has `fpclassify()` since C99.  It will allow you to check for exceptional floating point values (NaNs, infinities, and subnormals), which is what you need in order to implement a function providing the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this, since I want to maintain continuity. It works with opencl as well, and doesn't require any C99 stuff.

```
float nan_to_num(float num){
  if (isinf(num)){
    if (signbit(num))
      return -MAXFLOAT;
    else
      return MAXFLOAT;
  } else {
    return num;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using opencl C, which is only a subset of C99.

Comment: That makes sense, but should definitely have been added to the question!

Comment: signbit returns true for negative numbers. So if true the return should be -MAXFLOAT and else MAXFLOAT.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <math.h>

double normalize(double num)
    if (isnormal(num)){
        return num;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If infinity is to be treated specially, you could also use `isinf(num)` as a condition and return a 'big' number of your choice.